# How to insert text from a different file in tkinter without creating a new window

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I've been trying to figure out this problem for a while now, but I'm stumped.
I'm working on a text story-based game for class and I got the idea of putting the script in a different file, just to make it easier to manage. This means that I have the main function that runs the GUI that takes the input, sends it to the script file, the script file decides what text needs to be displayed, and calls a function in the main function that displays the chosen text.

My problem is that every time the main's function to display text is called, an entire new window is created with that text. This problem only happens when I call the function from outside main.
I need the output to be displayed on the existing window from a separate file, not create a new window.

my code is here (main on top, script on bottom):

**MAIN**

```
from tkinter import *
import script


class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
    self.root.geometry("300x400")

    Frame.__init__(self, self.root)
    self.create_widgets()


    def create_widgets(self):
        self.grid()
        self.text = Text(self, height=10, width=40, fg="black", bg="dark khaki")  # Output box
        self.vsb = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical",command=self.text.yview)  # Scrollbar
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.text.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.root.bind('<Return>', self.input)  # I forgot to mention, I have the enter key set to returning whatever's in the input box

        self.submit = Entry(self, width=30, bg="grey")
        self.submit.grid(column=0, row=1)  # input box


    def input(self, event):
        inp = self.submit.get()  # get what's in the input box
        self.submit.delete(0, END)  # clear the output box
        script.Script().inputP2(inp)  # sending the input to


    def insert(self, indent, inserting):
        if indent:  # I have two different settings to make inserting text easier
            self.text.insert(END, "\n{}".format(inserting))
        if not indent:
            self.text.insert(END, inserting)
        self.text.see("end")  # jump to the bottom of the output box


    def start(self):
        self.insert(False, "Game by me")
        self.root.mainloop()


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI().start()
```

**SCRIPT**

```
import main
from tkinter import *

class Script():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def inputP2(self, inp):
        if inp == "try":
            main.GUI().insert(False, "sucess!")

        # The real script is much longer, this is just an example
```

Comment: Don't call the insert function of the main thread from your script; rather, `return` the result of processing the input and let the main thread handle dealing with the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to have the main function call the script's function which will then call the main script's function. In order to execute your idea you mentioned at the beginning to separate the "script" part, we should separate it completely so that it is a building block that can be used again later if needed. Let the script to the processing, and *return* the result of the processing back to main, which handles the printing/erasing of things from the GUI window.

## Main

```
def input(self, event):
    inp = self.submit.get()  # get what's in the input box
    self.submit.delete(0, END)  # clear the output box
    result = script.Script().inputP2(inp)  # sending the input 
    self.insert(result)
```

## Script

```
# remove importing of main and tkinter in "script"
def inputP2(self, inp):
    if inp == "try":
        return (False, "sucess!")
```

Comment: Your use of terminology is a bit off. There's only a single thread in this code.